# Completing threads and interacting with results at a different rate

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I'd like to get some feedback on an approach for receiving data from multiple threads in a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` and iterating over the results.  Given the scenario a `ThreadPoolExecutor` has future thread results appended to a buffer container and a secondary / decoupled operation read and withdraw from the same buffer container.

**Thread Manager Workflow**

```
                    /|-> Thread 1 > results \
ThreadPoolExecutor --|-> Thread 2 > results --> Queue [1,2,3] (end) 
                    \|-> Thread 3 > results /
```

Now we have results from the threads in a First-In-First-Out queue container - which needs to be thread-safe. Now the above process is done and results `(str|int|bool|list|dict|any)` are in the container awaiting processing by the next step: Communicate the gathered results.

**Communication Workflow**

```
                                           /|-> Terminal Print
Queue [1,2,3] < Listener > Communicate --|-> Speech Engine Say 
                                           \|-> Write to Log / File
```

The `Communicate` class needs to be "listening" on the `Queue` for new entries, and processing each as they come in at it's own speed (the rate of speech using a text to speech module - [Producer-Consumer Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem)) and potentially any number of other outputs, so this really can't be invoked from the top-down.  If, the Thread Manager calls directly or lets each thread call the `Communicate` class directly to invoke the Speech Engine we will hear stuttered speech as the speech engine will override itself with each invocation.  Thus, we need to decouple the Thread Manager workflow from the Communicate workflow but have them write & read with an In/Out type buffer or `Queue` and need for a "listener" concept.

I've found references for a structure like the following running as a daemon thread, but the while loop makes me cringe and consumes too much cpu, so I still need a non-blocking approach, where `self.pipeline` is a `queue.Queue` object:

```
    while True :
        try :
            if not self.pipeline.empty ( ) :    
                task = self.pipeline.get ( timeout=1 )
                if task :       
                    self.serve ( task, )
        except queue.Empty :
            continue
```

Again, in need of something other than a while loop for this...

Comment: Think I'm looking for `queue.Queue` ... I'll keep you posted

Comment: With some more researching and understanding of my issue, it seems I'm talking about the standard Producer-Consumer Problem faced in threading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you use multiprocessing rather than threading to ensure maximum parallelism. I am not sure whether you really need a process pool for what you are trying to do rather than 4 dedicated processes; it's a question of how "threads" 1 through 3 are getting their data for feeding to the queue to be processed by the 4th process. Are these implemented by a single, identical worker function to whom "jobs" are submitted? If so then a process pool of 3 identical workers *is* what you want. But if these are 3 separate functions with their own processing logic, then you just want to create 3 `Process` instances. I am working on the second assumption.

Since we are now in the realm of multiprocessing, I would suggest using a "managed" `Queue` instance created with the following code:

```
with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
    q = manager.Queue()
```

Access to such a queue is synchronized across processeses. The following code is a rough idea of creating the processes and accessing the queue:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

class Communicate:
    def listen(self, q):
        while True:
            obj = q.get()
            if obj == None: # our signal to terminate
                return
            # do something with objects
            print(obj)

def process1(q):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        q.put(1)

def process2(q):
    while True:
        time.sleep(.5)
        q.put(2)

def process3(q):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1.5)
        q.put(3)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    communicator = Communicate()
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        #start the commmunicator process:
        q = manager.Queue()
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=communicator.listen, args=(q,))
        p.start()
        # start the other 3 processes:
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process1, args=(q,))
        p1.daemon = True
        p1.start()
        # start the other 3 processes:
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process2, args=(q,))
        p2.daemon = True
        p2.start()
        # start the other 3 processes:
        p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process3, args=(q,))
        p3.daemon = True
        p3.start()
        input('Hit any enter to terminate\n')
        q.put(None) # signal for termination
        p.join() # wait for process to complete
```

Answer (score 3):

As you write in the comments, its standard producer consumer problem. One solution in python is using multithreading and the [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue) class
The queue is thread safe . Its using a [mutex](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/96a09df64483b70c4215c7025a19b9d2f1636c55/Lib/queue.py#L46) internally, which handles busy waiting.

`Queue.get` will eventually call [wait](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/96a09df64483b70c4215c7025a19b9d2f1636c55/Lib/queue.py#L171) on its internal mutex. This will block the calling thread . But instead of busy waiting , which is using cpu, the thread will be put in sleep state. A thread scheduler of the os will take over from here, and will wake up the thread , when items are available (simplified ).

So you can still have `while True` loops within multiple thread consumers which call `queue.get` on shared queue. If items are available the threads directly process them, if not, they go into sleep mode and free the cpu. Same goes for producer threads , they simply call `Queue.put`

However there is one caveat in python. Python has something called global interpreter lock - GIL. This is because it is using a lot of c extension and allows modules which bring in c extensions. But those are not always thread safe. A GIL means, that only one thread will run on only one cpu at a time.

So , once an item is in the queue, only one consumer at a time will wake up and process the result. Also normally one producer can run at a time.
Except those threads start waiting for some I/O, like reading from a socket. Because I/O notification is handled by some other cpu part, there is always some waiting time for I/O. In that time, the threads release the GIL and other threads can do the work.

Summed up, it only makes sense to have multiple consumers and producer threads if they also do some I/O work - read/write on a network socket or disk. This is called concurrency. If you want to use multiple cpu cores at same time, you need to use multiprocessing in python instead of threads.
And it only makes sense to have more processes than cores, if there is also some IO work.

[Example](https://techmonger.github.io/55/producer-consumer-python/)

Comment: Re, "A GIL means, that only one thread will run on only one cpu at a time." You could say that even though C-Python threads can run [_concurrently_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing), the GIL prevents them from running [_in parallel_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing): A multi-threaded Python program running on a multi-CPU host can not get any more CPU cycles in a given span of time than it would get if the host had just one CPU.